# How do you connect from ODP.NET to Oracle (12G+) by proxy user with no password

Tags: c#, oracle, proxy, connection, odp.net

There seems to be no answer online as to how you can use Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) to connect to Oracle (12G and later) in a very specific scenario:

- User is identified externally on a database
- User is granted access to another schema (application user) by proxy connect

User has been set up like this:

```
CREATE USER user_in_question
IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY
-- etc.
```

And connect by proxy has been set up like this:

```
ALTER USER specified_app_user GRANT CONNECT THROUGH user_in_question
```

The logical approach when creating the ODP.NET OracleConnection string would be something like this (using the user friendly OracleConnectionStringBuilder):

```
var connBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
{
    UserID = "/", // External login using the user running the program 
    ProxyUserId = "specified_app_user", 
    DataSource = "database",
};
```

This does not work. Nor does providing blank "Password" or blank "Proxy Password". Nor does removing the UserId.

So how do you connect using ODP.NET in these circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (which I spend an hour searching for without any luck) is actually really simple, yet not very user friendly:

```
 var connBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
 {
     UserID = "[specified_app_user]",
     DataSource = "database",
 };
 //connBuilder.ToString() output:
 //"USER ID=[specified_app_user];DATA SOURCE=database"
```

This works in .NET 4.5+ on Oracle 12G+, but probably also on earlier platforms of .NET/Oracle/ODP.NET. I did not test it in ASP.NET, but it should work there too.

This way the UserId actually functions just like the ProxyUserId, just enclosed within brackets, just as you would normally log in on the Oracle Database using, say, Toad or SQlPlus.

It might also be possible using this format (but in my case the connection string had to be compatible with the OraOLEDB format so that did not work):

```
//Without the use of the conn string builder class, just for the fun of it...
var connString = "User Id=specified_app_user;Data Source=database;Proxy User Id=/";
```

EDITED 2nd March 2017: The line above does not seem to work in certain cases. Added comment about it and here is the code that IS working:

```
USER ID=[specified_app_user];DATA SOURCE=database
```

This info does not seem to exist anywhere - else I overlooked it, and in that case PLEASE do correct me.

Comment: Note that specified app user does not have brackets when connection string is specified using Proxy User Id=/

Comment: This is also a valid format: var connBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder { UserID = "specified_app_user", DataSource = "database", ProxyUserId = "/" } Then brackets are not needed because the proxy user id is specified as / (current user)

Comment: It seems that although "User Id=specified_app_user;Data Source=database;Proxy User Id=/" SHOULD work, it does not always. The correct working way is to include [] around the target schema:

    USER ID=[specified_app_user];DATA SOURCE=database

Comment: What if my own user is also an SQL-login, i.e. not an external user? Where in the connection string would my own username and the app_username go?

Comment: If you mean that your user is identified by a password you should be able to provide a password in the password part of the connection string. It is described in Oracle here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/proxy-users-and-connect-through : CREATE USER test_user IDENTIFIED BY test_user; ALTER USER scott GRANT CONNECT THROUGH test_user; CONN test_user[scott]/test_user; this should translate to 
"User Id=specified_app_user;Data Source=database;Proxy User Id=/;Password=myPassword" or likewise

Comment: Cheers. I made it work. I used my own username and password in the Proxy User ID and Proxy Password, and the "app user" as User Id, and left Password blank. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195399/oracle-connecting-as-a-proxy-user-via-connection-string

Comment: Great to hear - I read your post and everything makes sense - that the default "/" in Proxy User Id just needed to be substituted with your username and a Password field added.